# On page load pass user id stored in PHP session to AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

My controller method:

```
$scope.u = DbResourceSrv.getDbResource('restful.php', 'user', 1)
   .then(function(data){
       $scope.u = data;
       angular.forEach($scope.u, function(value, key){
          $scope.u.push( {key: value} );
       });
   });
```

As you can see, at this point I have hardcoded integer 1 there. I need to replace that with a variable that has been passed the correct value of that user's ID on page load.

I've already tried with a hidden form field but that quickly started to look weird. Then I tried with calling some method on `ng-init=(myMethod(php session val here))` but somehow after setting the value onto the scope in that `init-ed` method it wouldn't be read if placed where now "1" is.

Any ideas? I'd like to avoid creating and using a directive for this purpose because I have it working when the right value is there (hardcoded). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used `ng-init` to initialize the value. Couldn't find a better and more elegant solution.